# How to show keyboard when select specific row in pickerview

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, swift5

```
    var emailPickers:[String] = ["naver.com", "hanmail.net", "daum.net", "gmail.com", "nate.com", "input by myself"]
```

I want to: if picker's selected row index is 5 ("input by myself"), remove pickerview and show keyboard and can input textfield

please help me. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do the following steps this may helps you

if you select the option "input by myself" from picker then

```
yourTextField.resignFirstResponder()
```

then update your text filed input view from picker view to nil

```
yourTextField.inputView = nil
```

then make your text field active again with becomeFirstResponder

```
yourTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Hope this may helps you